# ggplot 2 does not display legend name

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a lowess curve with group interactions using ggplot2. This is my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=x, linetype=factor(group))) +    
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, color="black") +  
  scale_color_manual(name="groups", values= c("0", "1"), labels=c("group1", "group2")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed"))
```

The line types are correctly plotted, however it does not change the legend title and labels. Am I accidentely overriding the command?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are just using `linetype=` inside the `aes()` you don't need `scale_color_manual()` line but all atributes should be written inside the `scale_linetype_manual().`

```
+ scale_linetype_manual(name="groups",values = c("solid", "dashed"),
               labels=c("group1", "group2"))
```